# Application hangs when providing credentials for authenticated access to App Engine backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a problem with using authenticated calls from Android to my Google App Engine backend. When supplying credentials to the App.Builder call, nothing happens when executing the call to the backend - it does work when the parameter is null. Anyone knows what might cause this?

I have tried the following methods:

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, Collections.singleton("oauth2: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"));

GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(context, "server:client_id:"+WEB_CLIENT_ID);
```

With:

```
credential.setSelectedAccountName(SessionHandler.getCurrentAccountName());

App.Builder builder = new App.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential);
```

When executing the endpoint-calls, the application just hangs, presumably waiting for the call to return. The backend receives nothing.

It works when passing null instead of the credentials:

```
App.Builder builder = new App.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), null);
```

Comment: Does it hang if you call via API explorer?

Comment: Nope, it works via the API explorer :O

Comment: Your sample mentions `WEB_CLIENT_ID` but you probably want to use an Android client ID.

Comment: It didn't work using the Android Client ID either, thanks for your help anyway! We have decided to go another route instead :)